# Restart auto-increment on the next value of the another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to make it in such a way that I get:

> Main    | Column            I want to reset on new main value
>
> ```
> 1   | 100
> 1   | 101
> 1   | 102
> 1   | 103
> 1   | 104
> 2   | 100
> 2   | 101
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MyIsam engine to achieve this -

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  id1 INT(11) NOT NULL,
  id2 INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, NULL);

SELECT * FROM table1;
+-----+-----+
| id1 | id2 |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   1 |
|   1 |   2 |
|   2 |   1 |
|   2 |   2 |
+-----+-----+
```